# Topological continuity of $f(x)=|x|$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm going through the continuity section of *Schaum's General Topology* and this example has stumped me, conceptually speaking.

[image]

---

I'm having trouble making sense of much of any of the various pieces of $f^{-1}[A]$. Namely, the fact that $f^{-1}[A] = \varnothing$ if $a<b \leq 0$. Is this because if $a$ and $b$ are less than zero, then $f[(a,b)] = (-a,-b)$ but this is a problem since $a <b \leq 0$ implies that $-b < -a$ which means our interval is written improperly? Is that where the $\varnothing$ comes from?

Furthermore, understanding the other two cases is lost on me. Any suggestions or hints on how I should reinterpret this example?

Comment: if $a$ and $b$ are less than zero, then there's no $x$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $\lvert x\rvert\in (a,b)$, because $\lvert x\rvert\ge0$

Comment: I think the trouble stems from confusing $f(C)$ (where $C$ is a subset of the domain) with $f^{-1}(D)$ (where $D$ is a subset of the codomain). What is the precise definition of $f^{-1}(D)$? What then is the definition of $f^{-1}\big( (a,b)\big)$ here?

Comment: So in the example I've provided, are they saying that $A$ is a subset of the codomain? Because I've been interpreting $A$ as a subset of the domain.

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a subset of the codomain

Comment: Oh that clears up so much now that I see it that way. I'm going to try to take another look at it - this time with $A$ as a subset of the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}[A]$ for $A=(a,b)$ with $a < b \le 0$ is just defined as all $x$ in $\Bbb R$ (the domain of $f$) that have $f(x) \in A$. But as $|x| \ge 0$ for all $x$, no $x$ exists such that $f(x) \in (a,b)$. No valid values for $x$ is written as $x \in \emptyset$ (the set of all such $x$ is empty..). So you have to look when the **values** of $f$ are in $A$; in your question you want to take the images of points in $A$...

Note that in the pictures $A$ is drawn on the $y$-axis... (so it talks about the values that $f$ assumes, it's irrelevant what $f(x)$ is for $x \in A$, the question is for what $x$ does the value lie in $A$?